# aiohttp: Should a ClientSession be re-used or created newly foreach request?

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I'm using Python 3.11 with aiohttp as a client to POST data to a server. In the end I'll be posting 3 million single requests to the same endpoint, just with different request bodies.

The server alone is quite fast.

```py
class MyClient:
    async def create(single_request_body: dict)->bool:
        """"returns true iff the request was successful"""
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(
                    "https://my-server.org/endpoint", data=single_request_body
                ) as response:
                     return response.status == 201
```

Now I'm processing my 3million POSTs like this:

```py
all_request_bodys: list[dict] = 3_000_000*[{...}]
my_client = MyClient()
all_post_tasks = [my_client.create(x) for x in all_request_bodies]
await asyncio.gather(*all_post_tasks)
```

And it's way too slow.

I'm wondering if this is the right way to do it and I was wondering if:

**Would it speed up my application, if the `ClientSession` was an instance variable of the client and I'd re-use the same session instead of creating new sessions for each POST?**

In my first tests it didn't seem so, but maybe I'm using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes your code definitely lead to performance issues. try this one:

```
class MyClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def create(self, single_request_body: dict) -> bool:
        """"returns True if the request was successful"""
        async with self.session.post("https://my-server.org/endpoint", data=single_request_body) as response:
            return response.status == 201

async def main():
    all_request_bodies = [{}] * 3_000_000  # Example list of request bodies
    my_client = MyClient()
    all_post_tasks = [my_client.create(x) for x in all_request_bodies]
    await asyncio.gather(*all_post_tasks)

# Run the event loop
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new session for each request implies a new TCP connection, including all the associated overhead. You create a session in order to reuse already [established connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection). With that said,

- you can further improve the performance by increasing the number of the concurrent open connections (by default 100). Note that this is specific to the server

```py
 connector = aiohttp.TCPConnector(limit=1000)  # Adjust as needed
 self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector)
```

- in aiohttp, sessions must be created inside a coroutine. You can pass it as an argument to the `create` function or instantiate it after creating `MyClient`

```py
class MyClient:
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = None

    async def create_session(self):
        self.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    async def create(self, single_request_body: dict) -> bool:
        if self.session is None:
            raise ValueError("create the session before calling")

        async with self.session.post(
            "https://my-server.org/endpoint", data=single_request_body
        ) as response:
            return response.status == 201
```